# How to create an evaluation function for a TIC-TAC-TOE variant game

Tags: artificial-intelligence, minmax, evaluation-function

I'm actually working on a board game which is a variant of the `TIC-TAC-TOE` game. The specifics of the game are the followings :

**1.** The game is played on a `n`x`n` board, with `n` variable.

**2.** A player wins if he succeeds in placing `k` alignments the first, `k` is variable.

**3.** An alignment is constituted of `l` marks (**X** or **O**) in a horizontal, vertical or diagonal. `l` is fixed.

**4.** If the `n`x`n` grid is full (no player can add a mark either **X** or **O**) and no player succeeded in placing `k` alignments so the game is drawn.

I'm using an `minmax` with `alpha-beta prunning` algorithm. This is my first program with artificial intelligence and I don't know exactly how to create the evaluation function to be used by the algorithm. I saw some examples on the net which use a material weighting to evaluate a position but I can't apply that in my case.  Actually, I'm using a radom evaluation function which returns a value between `-100` and `100`.

```
    float Conf_eval(Configuration c)
       {
         return (rand()%201)-100;
       }
```

Any idea on how can I evaluate a given board configuration ?

Comment: In games, for which finding a good heuristics is too hard, the Monte Carlo approach seems to work the best (with the great success in the board game GO).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is thoroughly discussed in the book [Artificial Intelligence - A Modern Approach](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CEMQFjAB&url=http://stpk.cs.rtu.lv/sites/all/files/stpk/materiali/MI/Artificial%2520Intelligence%2520A%2520Modern%2520Approach.pdf&ei=K2zEUo2YJY6WswbXtoCgBg&usg=AFQjCNGWuwp4bDR-YTsUKSSmKHPmcC7cPA&sig2=wkdNVfn2kCJjTZ7IFalMpA&bvm=bv.58187178,d.Yms)

There are also excellent [implementations](https://code.google.com/p/aima-java/) available (this is java, there is also [python](https://code.google.com/p/aima-python/), you can Google for more) based on the book series. Including for tic-tac-toe (and alpha-beta pruning agents).

If you're using the [min-max algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax) with [alpha-beta prunning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha%E2%80%93beta_pruning), you can use a sorted "Actions" list to perform better in addition to your heuristic function (a trivial **utility**-function would be assigning 1 to a victory, 0 to a tie and -1 to a loss - these are all leaf nodes of the min-max expanded tree).

To sort the actions you can, for say, prefer actions that add your symbol(**X**, **O**) to a clear-to-victory path. This should eventually lead to better prunning.

Comment: what do you mean by a sorted "Actions" list?

Comment: The min-max algorithm is based on actions. You apply an action on a state and the result is a new state. If you have the "available Actions" list sorted by what you think yields the best results - you can have better prunning by getting the "good" results for each player faster (that is, if you're right).

Comment: Thanks for the links. I started to build a linear evaluation function.

Comment: Good luck, can't say I'm an expert, and you may have better luck asking here: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/